# How i can deserialize LocalDateTime into LocalDate using a REST controller GET where value in response is LocalDateTime, value in DTO is LocalDate?

Tags: java, spring, serialization, annotations, converters

I found a lot of information about converting / deserializing LocalDate to LocalDateTime, but did not find about LocalDateTime in LocalDate, in the case when we use a REST request, where the response contains a value with the format LocalDateTime and the DTO where this value is written has LocalDate.

DTO which fill from response body

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ContractDto {
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    @JsonProperty(value = "date")
    private LocalDate date;
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    @JsonProperty(value = "begin_date")
    private LocalDate beginDate;
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    @JsonProperty(value = "end_date")
    private LocalDate endDate;
}
```

Example how looks by response body (some other values was deleted for best reading)

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "date": "2015-11-16T00:00:00+03:00",
            "begin_date": "2015-11-16T00:00:00+03:00",
            "end_date": "2025-04-30T00:00:00+03:00"
        },
    ]
}
```

Error which i've deserve ;D

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [ru.tfm.connector.model.dto.ResultDto<ru.tfm.transport.model.dto.connector.ContractDto>] and content type [application/json]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "2015-11-16T00:00:00+03:00": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDate: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2015-11-16T00:00:00+03:00' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "2015-11-16T00:00:00+03:00": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDate: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2015-11-16T00:00:00+03:00' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 6, column: 12] (through reference chain: ru.tfm.connector.model.dto.ResultDto["result"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->ru.tfm.transport.model.dto.connector.ContractDto["date"])] with root cause
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2015-11-16T00:00:00+03:00' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10
```

What i've tried:

1. @JsonParser annotation
2. @DateFormat annotation

What i think to try:

1. Custom converter for Jackson?
2. Custom deserializer?

Thanks a Lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this annotations:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class) 
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
```